# Running “php -f file.php” prints the file contents instead of executing it

Tags: ubuntu, php

I have new freshly installed Ubuntu Unity (23.10) OS, where I installed PHP.

Now I want to run a PHP file from the terminal, but instead of executing it, it just print it contents. (The PHP file is from a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sectroyer/SmartCrypto/tree/master/SmartCrypto), and not mine.)

A simple file that prints "Hello world" works just fine.

There are no errors.

```php
marc@workstation:~/projects/playground/SmartCrypto2/SmartCrypto$ php smart.php
<?
require('tv_geturl.php');

$UserId = "654321";
$AppId = "12345";
$dest_hash = "";
$SKPrime = "";
$ctx = "";
//$Guid =  "7e509404-9d7c-46b4-8f6a-e2a9668ad184";
$deviceId =  "784c5390-73a2-441e-91d6-1980b114e866";
$hash = "";
$AES_key= "";
$lastRequestId = "";
$sessionId = 0;
$tvIP = "192.168.2.100";
$tvPort = "8080";

function getFullUrl($urlPath)
{
    global $tvIP, $tvPort;
    return "http://".$tvIP.":".$tvPort.$urlPath;
}
function GetFullRequestUri($step, $appId, $deviceId)
{
    return getFullUrl("/ws/pairing?step=".$step."&app_id=".$appId."&device_id=".$deviceId);
}
function CheckPinPageOnTv()
{
    $full_url = getFullUrl("/ws/apps/CloudPINPage");
    $page = geturl($full_url,$tvPort);
    if(preg_match("@<state>([^<>]*)</state>@si",$page,$out))
    {
        echo "Current state: ".$out[1]."\n";
        if($out[1] == "stopped")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function ShowPinPageOnTv()
{
    geturl2(getFullUrl("/ws/apps/CloudPINPage"), "pin4");
}
function StartPairing()
{
    global $lastRequestId;
    $lastRequestId=0;
    if(CheckPinPageOnTv())
    {
        echo "Pin NOT on TV"."\n";
        ShowPinPageOnTv();
    }
    else
        echo "Pin ON TV"."\n";
}
function FirstStepOfPairing()
{
    global $AppId, $deviceId;
    $firstStepURL = GetFullRequestUri(0,$AppId, $deviceId)."&type=1";
    //echo("firstStepURL: '".$firstStepURL."'\n");
    $firstStepResponse = geturl($firstStepURL);
    //echo ("firstStepResponse: ".$firstStepResponse."");
}
function GenerateServerHello($pin)
{
    global $UserId ,$hash,$AES_key;
    $res = shell_exec("./smartcrypto generateServerHello $UserId $pin");
    if(preg_match("@AES key: ([^ \n]*).*hash: ([^ \n]*).*ServerHello: ([^ \n]*)@si",$res,$out))
    {
        $AES_key = $out[1];
        $hash = $out[2];
        return $out[3];
    }
    return false;
}
function parseClientHello($clientHello)
{
    global $UserId, $hash, $AES_key,$dest_hash, $SKPrime, $ctx;
    $res = shell_exec("./smartcrypto parseClientHello $clientHello $hash $AES_key $UserId");
    if(preg_match("@dest_hash: ([^ \n]*).*SKPrime: ([^ \n]*).*ctx: ([^ \n]*)@si",$res,$out))
    {
        $dest_hash = $out[1];
        $SKPrime = $out[2];
        $ctx = $out[3];
        echo "dest_hash: $dest_hash\n";
        echo "SKPrime: $SKPrime\n";
        echo "ctx: $ctx\n";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
function HelloExchange($pin)
{
    global $AppId, $deviceId, $lastRequestId, $hash, $AES_key;
    $serverHello = GenerateServerHello($pin);
    if(!$serverHello)
        return false;
    $content = "{\"auth_Data\":{\"auth_type\":\"SPC\",\"GeneratorServerHello\":\"".$serverHello."\"}}";
    $secondStepURL = GetFullRequestUri(1,$AppId, $deviceId);
    //echo "secondStepURL: '".$secondStepURL."'\n";
    //echo "secondStep content: '".$content."'\n";
    $secondStepResponse = geturl2($secondStepURL,$content);
    //echo "secondStepResponse: ".$secondStepResponse."";
    if(!preg_match("@request_id.*?(\d).*?GeneratorClientHello.*?:.*?(\d[0-9a-zA-Z]*)@si",$secondStepResponse,$out))
        return false;
    #var_dump($out);
    $requestId = $out[1];
    $clientHello = $out[2];
    //echo "clientHello: '".$clientHello."'\n";
    //echo "requestId: '".$requestId."'\n";
    //echo "hash: '".$hash."'\n";
    //echo "AES key: '".$AES_key."'\n";
    $lastRequestId = $requestId; 
    return parseClientHello($clientHello);
}
function generateServerAcknowledge()
{
    global $SKPrime;
    $SKPrimeHash = sha1(hex2bin($SKPrime."01"));
    return "0103000000000000000014".strtoupper($SKPrimeHash)."0000000000";
}
function ParseClientAcknowledge($clientAck)
{
    global $SKPrime;
    $SKPrimeHash = sha1(hex2bin($SKPrime."02"));
    $tmpClientAck = "0104000000000000000014".strtoupper($SKPrimeHash)."0000000000";
    return $clientAck === $tmpClientAck;
}
function AcknowledgeExchange()
{
    global $lastRequestId,$AppId, $deviceId, $sessionId;
    $serverAckMessage = generateServerAcknowledge();
    $content="{\"auth_Data\":{\"auth_type\":\"SPC\",\"request_id\":\"".$lastRequestId."\",\"ServerAckMsg\":\"".$serverAckMessage."\"}}";
    $thirdStepURL = GetFullRequestUri(2,$AppId, $deviceId);
    //echo "thirdStepURL: '".$thirdStepURL."'\n";
    //echo "thirdStep content: $content\n";
    $thirdStepResponse = geturl2($thirdStepURL,$content);
    //echo "thirdStepResponse: '$thirdStepResponse'";
    if(strstr($thirdStepResponse,"secure-mode"))
    {
        echo "TODO: Implement handling of encryption flag!!!!\n";
        die(-1);
    }
    if(!preg_match("@ClientAckMsg.*?:.*?(\d[0-9a-zA-Z]*).*?session_id.*?(\d)@si",$thirdStepResponse,$out))
    {
        echo "Unable to get session_id and/or ClientAckMsg!!!\n";
        die(-1);
    }
    $clientAck = $out[1];
    //echo "clientAck: '$clientAck'\n";
    if(!ParseClientAcknowledge($clientAck))
    {
        echo "Parse client ac message failed.\n";
        die(-1);
    }
    $sessionId=$out[2];
    echo "sessionId: $sessionId\n";
    return $sessionId;
}
function ClosePinPageOnTv()
{
    geturl(getFullUrl("/ws/apps/CloudPINPage/run"),"DELETE");
   return false;
}
StartPairing();
$pinAccepted = false;
do 
{
    echo "Please enter pin from tv:\n";
    $tvPIN = readline();
    echo "Got pin: '".$tvPIN."'\n";
    FirstStepOfPairing();
    $pinAccepted=HelloExchange($tvPIN);
    if($pinAccepted)
        echo "Pin accepted :)\n\n";
    else
        echo "Pin incorrect. Please try again...\n\n";
}while(!$pinAccepted);
$currentSessionId = AcknowledgeExchange();
ClosePinPageOnTv();
echo "Authorization successfull :)\n\n";
?>
```

```sh
PHP 8.2.10-2ubuntu1 (cli) (built: Sep  5 2023 14:37:47) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.10-2ubuntu1, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Exit code is also 0.

Any ideas/hints?

Comment: The issue is the short code is `<?` instead of `<?php` which is what it should be. FWIW, I believe the `short_open_tags` setting setting has been set to `false`/`0` since PHP 5.3 which was released in 2009. PHP is now up to 8.3. So I would be wary of this PHP code if it is so out of date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is using `<?` to start the PHP code. It should be using `<?php`.

Usage of bare `<?` requires having the `short_open_tags` PHP option enabled (through php.ini or similar). I wouldn't recommend that – it can result in conflicts with XML files (which use `<?xml` for their headers) and doesn't really save much typing anyway.

Even if the project is not yours, it seems to be a small enough project that it'll be simpler to change the `<?` opening tag to `<?php` on the two PHP files that it has (well, one, as the other already has the full open tag).

Comment: I believe the `short_open_tags` setting setting has been set to `false`/`0` since PHP 5.3 which was released in 2009. PHP is now up to 8.3. So I would be wary of this PHP code if it is so out of date.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it!

Comment: @Giacomo1968 disabled-by-default on *unix since at least 5.1-something, enabled-by-default on Windows even today: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aphp%2Fphp-src%20short_open_tag&type=code

Comment: @hanshenrik That is an amazing exception!

Comment: @hanshenrik: That looks like the hardcoded default if not set in php.ini – but it's set to 'Off' by default in php.ini, so functionally it's off by default?

Comment: @u1686_grawity there is no default php.ini, and in the absence of a php.ini, it is on-by-default on Windows to this day. There are 2 php.ini-templates (named `php.ini-production` and `php.ini-development`) and both templates disable it, so in practice people copy 1 of the templates to make their own php.ini, with it disabled :)

Answer (score 1):

The code use the `short_open_tag` which only works with the php.ini setting `short_open_tag=1` - invoking it with

```php
php -d short_open_tag=1 smart.php
```

would fix that particular problem.

However, looks to me like your code was written for PHP5 or older (maybe even PHP4?), and I doubt it will execute correctly on PHP8.2 even with `short_open_tag`.

FWIW, the `short_open_tag` is not recommended, and there has been several unsuccessful attempts to deprecate and remove `short_open_tag`. ([1](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags_v2), [2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags))

Comment: The code worked :D even on php 8.

Comment: @Marc gratz. i recommend you make a pull request to that repo to remove the short_open_tag dependency